Why does my code not check for the second button press?
Here is my code for checking both presses. I don't understand why does the second button doesn't work
proc whatPress
pusha
    call setUpMagicNumbers
    call startscreen
    mov ax,00
        int 33h
        mov ax,01
        int 33h
waitforpress:
;call Esc_end
        mov ax, 3
        int 33h
        
 cmp cx, 112
        jb waitforpress
        cmp cx, 452
        ja waitforpress
        cmp dx, 81
        jb waitforpress
        cmp dx, 153
        ja waitforpress
        cmp bx, 1h
        je startt
        ;-----------
        check_second_button:; Check for the second button press
    cmp cx, 336
    jb waitforpress
    cmp cx, 624
    ja waitforpress
    cmp dx, 157
    jb waitforpress
    cmp dx, 198
    ja waitforpress
    cmp bx, 1h
    je Rulejump
    jmp waitforpress
        startt:
        mov ax,02
        int 33h
        call clean
      call GamePlay
        popa
        ret
        Rulejump:
        call RuleWaitPress
        popa
        ret
endp whatPress


It's unclear what you want. However note that if the first block of coordinate checks fail, your code never gets to check_second_button obviously. You probably want to skip there instead of back to waitforpress in that block.

according to this, the code at check_second_button is being run/evaluated. (see: https://godbolt.org/z/MYchWxYxn ), but my assembly knowledge is limited, so I cannot help you any further...


I don't understand why does the second button doesn't work

First understand it
This is an approximation of where your two buttons are on the screen:
    
    
    
       **********************
       *                    *
       *      button 1      *
       *                    *
       **********************

                    *******************
                    *     button 2    *
                    *******************

For your program execution to arrive at check_second_button:, there are 5 conditions that need to be fulfilled. The coordinates in CX and DX must fall within the first button, and there must be no left mouse click.
So, if the coordinates are already pointing in the first button, and observing that there's no overlap between the buttons, we can't hope to register a click on the second button (since we're clearly outside of it)!
And even if some overlap would exist, it would still not work because BX would still be holding a number different from 1h, and so a jump to waitforpress would occur.
Then solve it
waitforpress:
  mov  ax, 0003h
  int  33h            ; -> BX CX DX
  test bx, 1
  jnz  waitforpress   ; Wait for left mouse button to be pressed

check_first_button:
  cmp  cx, 112
  jb   check_second_button
  cmp  cx, 452
  ja   check_second_button
  cmp  dx, 81
  jb   check_second_button
  cmp  dx, 153
  ja   check_second_button

  ; startt:
  mov  ax, 0002h
  int  33h
  call clean
  call GamePlay
  popa
  ret

check_second_button:
  cmp  cx, 336
  jb   waitforpress
  cmp  cx, 624
  ja   waitforpress
  cmp  dx, 157
  jb   waitforpress
  cmp  dx, 198
  ja   waitforpress
  ; Rulejump:
  call RuleWaitPress
  popa
  ret

